# How to list SVN repository name with latest revision number

Tags: shell, xargs

I want to get for each of my SVN repository its latest revision number. My command looks like currently like this:

```
ls | xargs -n 1 svnlook youngest
```

This prints a list of revision numbers. But I'd like to have it in the format `${repo_name} ${latest_revision`. Any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it. I used `paste` to interleave `svnlook youngest` with `ls`

```
paste <( ls | xargs -n 1 svnlook youngest) <(ls | tr " " "\n")
```